# Names for left- and right-total relations

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, relations

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. I am interested in *subsets* $r \subseteq X \times Y$, which contain each $x \in X$ and each $y \in Y$ at least once:
$$
\forall_{x \in X} \exists_{y \in Y} (x, y) \in r \land \forall_{y \in Y} \exists_{x \in X} (x, y) \in r .
$$
For example, one such subset is the whole product itself. In other words, I'm talking about "left-total" and "right-total" relations.

**My question**: Are such relations known under other names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In universal algebra, a subalgebra of a direct product with this property is called "subdirect".

By the way, [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) validates your terminology.

Comment: A great example of a proper subdirect product is commonly (but questionably) attributed to Abraham Lincoln: "You can fool all the people some of the time, and some of the people all of the time, but you cannot fool all of the people all of the time."